# override pyproject.toml settings on command line

Tags: python, pep517

When building a python project using the python [build](https://github.com/pypa/build) module, is there a way to override settings in pyproject.toml on the command line?

For instance, suppose `pyproject.toml` contains:

```
[build-system]
build-backend = "foo"
```

I would like to know if it is possible to override `foo` (say with `myfoo`) on the command line `python -m build`.  This is just an example.

My question is more general than that example.  Whatever upstream defined in a pyproject.toml, a downstream user/packager may want or need to override something that upstream defined for any number of reasons.

Comment: From a quick glance at the `build` package, there's no configurable way that I can see to do this. My immediate thought is that you could copy the project or sdist, and use `tomllib` to rewrite the pyproject.toml file with your desired changes. Then build the copied+mutated directory

Comment: Can you add some more context for why you'd want this? Are you trying to test new versions of your backend on existing packages? Or testing migrating to a new backend altogether?

Comment: @flakes - Regarding more context, I added more about possible motivations in the question.  But for the specific case of changing the name of the backend tool that the upstream project defined, a downstream user may be using a platform where the backend may have a different name, or as you say the user may desire to test alternative versions of the backend without having to modify pyproject.toml for each testing iteration.

Comment: For the general case, I think you'd probably want to look at copying the source and modifying the pyproject.toml manually or using `tomllib` to manipulate it once copied. For overriding packages that get installed as backend components, you could look into using [devpi](https://pypi.org/project/devpi/) or `pypiserver` package to provide an override to the pypi server used for creating venvs. I did something similar here https://github.com/devpi/devpi/issues/932